# converting ascii to an interger (C)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, ascii

I'm brand new to C and i'm working on a method that converts an ascii to an integer. So bascially if i have  ABCD (base 16) ill get 43981 (base 10).. Just a short walk through of what i have. I take one digit at i time from the string then that number needs to be translated so i call my chartoint method. Then i think i need to * the pervious result by the base before i add the new number. I am also confused on the printf method. Here is my method so far.

```
void ascii2int(char *ascii, int base){
    int totalstring = 0;    
    if(2<= base && base <= 16){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ascii); i++) {
            // Extract a character
            char c = ascii[i];
            // Run the character through char2int
            int digit = char2int(c);
            totalstring= digit * base;
            printf("%d/n",totalstring);
        }
    }
}
```

char2int

```
 int char2int(char digit){
    int converted = 0;   
    if(digit >= '0' && digit <= '9'){
    converted = digit - '0';
    }   
    else if( digit >= 'A' && digit <= 'F'){
    converted = digit - 'A' + 10;       
    }
    else{
    converted = -1;}
return converted;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that function `char2int` is implemented correctly...

Change this:

```
totalstring = digit * base;
```

To this:

```
totalstring *= base;  // totalstring = totalstring * base
totalstring += digit; // totalstring = totalstring + digit
```

Or to this:

```
totalstring = totalstring * base + digit;
```

In addition, call `printf` **outside** the `for` loop (and change that `/n` to `\n`).

Comment: +1 if you explain `*=` and `+=`. :) (Rationale: implementing atoi is the prime example where users for the first time use `*=` and `+=`.)

Comment: totalstring = totalstring * base |||
totalstring = totalstring + digit

Comment: i've acutally tried that before and my ouput is still off. i get ABCD (base 16) = 10171274843981 (base 10)

Comment: @dave: As I mentioned at the beginning of the answer - "Assuming that function `char2int` is implemented correctly". You have not provided it in the code, so we have no way of knowing...

Comment: @dave: Possibly because you're printing it at the end of **every iteration** instead of at the end of the entire loop.

Comment: @dave: You can accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
void ascii2int(char *ascii, int base){
//int digit = 0;    
int totalstring = 0;    
if(2<= base && base <= 16){ 
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ascii); i++) {
    // Extract a character
    char c = ascii[i];
    // Run the character through char2int
    int digit = char2int(c);
totalstring = totalstring * base + digit;
        }
printf("%d", totalstring);

}
```

}